# Multivariable Power BI Scatterplot?

Tags: powerbi, scatter-plot

My question is similar to this question here:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Multi-variable-Scatter-Plot/m-p/312013#M138304

I understand that you can only display one variable on the x-axis of a PowerBI scatterplot.  But, I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to toggle on/off multiple variables on the scatterplot.  For example, the Y-Axis wouldn't change, but you could add/remove different variables to display on the x-axis.

My variables are all in date format, so it would be great to overlay different variables on the x-axis, i.e. "event1", "event2", "event3", so that you could see them in relation to one another.  Is this possible?  PowerBI has virtually no documentation that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about multiple variables, but you can at least change the variable to display in the axis based on a slicer.

The steps:

1. Create 2 new tables, each representing the possible values on each axis (Just the labels and an index);
2. Create measures with the values you'll want to see in the axis (ex: Total Sales);
3. In each table, create a new Measure with a Switch that maps the labels to the created measures.

Ex:

```
Measure Selection I = 
IF(ISCROSSFILTERED('Measure Selection I'[Measure I]);
SWITCH(
    TRUE();
    VALUES('Measure Selection I'[Measure I])  = "Danceability";[Total Danceability];
    VALUES('Measure Selection I'[Measure I])  = "Energy";[Total Energy];    
    );
    Blank())
```

4. Create the Visual and the slicers, and put the created measures in the corresponding places.

Here is a video with an example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYbGNeYD4OY

Comment: Dreekun - thanks!  Can I do this given that all my data exists in one excel table?  I can take a look at this.

Comment: In that case, do I need to follow step 1: create 2 new tables?  Or can I work within one table?  thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to create the tables so that you have a corresponding value for your switch function. If the values for the axis are the same, one table is enough. You create them in Power Query, with Enter Data, manually. 
It's like this: http://prntscr.com/q9fsh7
I think the video will explain better.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 did it work? Can you upvote so I can get some reputation and be able to comment on posts? Thank you.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 thank you! Now I can upvote your post :)

Comment: Dreekun - I've figured out how to change the variable displayed on the x-axis using a slicer , but it only let's me choose one variable at a time to display.  Is there a way to display multiple variables at once?

Comment: Not that I know of, like I said in my first sentence.